# Pass Props Between Routes Using React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is the only way to pass data between routes in React-Router (1.0.0-rc) url params? I have a component, A, which uses the History mixin, and has an event handler that makes a server request and then calls `that.history.pushState(null, '/B');` to transition to route B handled by component B. 
Now, I would like to pass some of the data I am returned by the server to component B as a prop (e.g. "login successful"), or somehow affect the state of B, but I can't find any documentation stating this is possible. Is there any way to do this, or do I need to pass it as a url parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. pass the data as a query params
2. keep the state of the application somewhere else, outside of the routes

For #2 you could use something like [redux](http://rackt.github.io/redux/) which will keep a 'global' store of the application state. You can then access this state from both component `A` and `B`.

Comment: I'm attempting #1 using query params but so far I'm not having luck using react-router.

Comment: For the second case. Are there other options besides redux (and other flux-like)?

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage or sessionsessionstorage. Set data in first router, get it on second router using set and get item of localstorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage